# Siblings give Object #<HTMLSelectElement> has no method 'each'

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I missing here?

As part of an answer to [How can i change options in dropdowns if it is generated dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872713/how-can-i-change-options-in-dropdowns-if-it-is-generated-dynamically/12872774#comment17428921_12872774)

I have an issue inside an onchange. I want to set all the siblings values to the value of the changed select

```
$("select").on("change",function() {
  var idx=$(this).val();
  console.log($(this).attr("id"),$(this).val())
  $(this).siblings("select").each(function() {
     $(this).val(idx);
  });
});
```

Here is the generated code in a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/wPyHc/)

I have seen

[How do i get the value of all other dropdowns when one of them is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896009/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-all-other-dropdowns-when-one-of-them-is-changed)

but I prefer to find the reason for my error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `val` method  as a property.

```
var idx=$(this).val;
//            ----^
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vr5Je/

You can also use the `val` method instead of `each`:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $(this).siblings("select").val(this.value);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Pq2vq/

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the problem... The `each` making the error isn't the one visible in OP's code !

Comment: Thanks - will accept in 5 minutes - very confusing that the each gives such an error...

Comment: @mplungjan You are welcome, actually the error is related to undefined value.

Comment: `$(this).siblings("select").val(idx)` will also change all siblings without `each` loop or function argument

Comment: @undefined  Your fiddle has syntax error ( extra braces). See: http://jsfiddle.net/G6mDS/1/ `val(value)` will work on a collection

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, it has. I know it works, it also accepts an array for _multiple_ select element. I was very sleepy and didn't debug it.